# Check if DTC service is turned on in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msdtc

When Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) is not running, our MVC C# site throws strange misleading errors, confusing developers and testers.  We want to do a code check that the service is running and flag the issue on something like Global.asax.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code starts the MSDTC service on the local machine if it's currently "Stopped"

You need to reference the **System.ServiceProcess** assembly

```
using(var msDtcSvc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("MSDTC"))
{
    if(msDtcSvc.Status == System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
    {
        msDtcSvc.Start();
    }
}
```